# double differential equation with a constant

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do I solve this equation:

$\frac{d^2y(t)}{dt^2} = -\frac{k}{2m}y(t) + (g +\frac{kl_0}{2m})$

I know how to solve

$\frac{d^2y(t)}{dt^2} = -\frac{k}{2m}y(t) $

But how do I deal with this constant term?

Comment: make a change of variable $y = u + k$ where $k$ is a constant, so that you get a homogeneous equation for $u.$

Comment: It is too wide issue. HINT: "Improper" try substitution: $\frac{k}{2m}y(t) - (g +\frac{kl_0}{2m}) = z(t)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you know about the homogeneous solutions. Now find the particular solutions with the constant trial function $y(t)=A$. The general solution is homogeneous plus particular solution.

Comment: I think I need to read up on that. But thanks.